# Basic add list item with JavaScript problem

Tags: javascript, jsom

I am trying to create a list item with JavaScript, but have been having problems.

To try to simplify things, I created a simple list called "Test List" with one column, "Title" and created a script manager web part on the DispForm.aspx as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Style%20Library/scripts/SharepointJSOM.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/Style%20Library/scripts/AddFakeItem.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<div id="addFakeButton">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-small" id="btnAddFake"
             onclick="AddFakeItem()">Add fake item</button>
</div>
```

which refers to AddFakeItem.js which is based on [stock MS code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BasicOps_SPListItemCRUD):

```
var list;
var loops = new Date();
$(function () {
    $("button#btnAddFake").click(AddFakeItem());
});

function AddFakeItem(s, e) {
    ExecSPObjModel(AddFake, s, e);
}

function AddFake(s, e) {
    if (!SP.ClientContext)
        throw {
            name: 'Context Null Exception',
            message: 'SP.ClientContext has not loaded.'
        }
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    //list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Test List");
    list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    if (!list) {
        alert("List not found");
        return;
    }
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    this.newItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    this.newItem.set_item("Title","Fake Item #" + ++loops);
    ctx.load(this.newItem);
    if ((1, eval)("this").newItem !== this.newItem)
        (1, eval)("this").newItem = this.newItem;
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    if (this.newItem)
        alert('Item created: ' + this.newItem.get_id());
    else if ((1, eval)("this").newItem)
        alert('Item created: ' + (1, eval)("this").newItem.get_id());
    else
        alert('No item returned');
}   
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

when I click the button, the script executes, but when it hits .executeQueryAsync, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?  Neither of the event handlers execute.

EDIT:  Here is the working version of John-M's code from below:

```
function createListItem(listId) {
    // I'm going to keep all of the variables within this function's scope;
    // including the callback functions so that they have access to the calling
    // function's variables 
    var cc = SP.ClientContext;
    var clientContext = cc.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'New item!' + ++loops);
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onCreateListItemSuccess, onCreateListItemFailed);
    function onCreateListItemSuccess() {
        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    }
    function onCreateListItemFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('createListItem request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}

var key = "sp.runtime.js";
var namespace = "SP.ClientContext";
SP.SOD.executeFunc(key, namespace, function () {
    console.log(key + ": Type available (" + namespace + ")");
}, false);
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
    // then you can come wire up this function to your button   
    $("#btnAddNewCode").click(function () {
        createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    });
}, key);
```

the last part is the details of was needed to get SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded working so that I didn't have to rely on ExecSPObjModel.

Comment: Creative (ab)use of ``(1, eval)("this")``. But you did not get that from the MSDN examples, Who taught you *this*? Because (in this code) is the same as ``window.newItem = ``

Comment: The answer almost assuredly lies within `ExecSPObjModel`, since it looks like you would have to use apply to call your `AddFake` function -- What are you trying to accomplish jumping through all the `eval` and `apply` indirection hoops anyway? In a function delegate (like you've created based on the MSDN example you can just use `this.newItem` since you already have the calling function for `this`

Comment: That is just some left-over cruft from debugging.  Essentially, I was ruling out bad object references by using the global scope -- (1, eval)("this")  Inside of ExecSPObjModel, this !=(1, eval)("this").    It is, however, unrelated to the issue at hand, as the error still happens identically with all of that stripped out.

Comment: You know what I am going to double down on my bet it has something to do with how you're calling the function in `ExecSPObjModel` because `Function.createDelegate` also uses `apply` internally.. try calling `AddFake` directly from the onclick or from within `AddFakeItem`

Comment: I place my bet behind John; what is *this* inside your function? If it is **not** the global context then ``this.onQuerySucceeded`` is ``undefined``. I say clean up your script, strip all that cruft. And I advice to make it work as a [Chrome Snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support) first; much easier to debug. And ``myfunc.bind(this)`` is modern ES5 code for oldschool ``Function.createDelegate(this, myfunc)``

Comment: As a newb to JSOM, I don't fully know what the ExecSPObjModel function does.  I really only know two things:  It does create a non-global "this" scope, and my attempts to run JSOM directly fail silently.  (I've had good luck retrieving data with ExecSPObjModel, but zero luck creating new items.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest ditching `ExecSPObjModel` and stick with the basics while you're getting up to speed with SharePoint's JavaScript Object Model.

Many of the MSDN examples make scoping more complicated than it needs to be... here is my suggestion to do the basic thing you're looking for:

```
function createListItem(listId) {
    // I'm going to keep all of the variables within this function's scope;
    // including the callback functions so that they have access to the calling
    // function's variables 
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'New item!');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onCreateListItemSuccess, onCreateListItemFailed);

    function onCreateListItemSuccess() {
        alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    }
    function onCreateListItemFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('createListItem request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
}
// then you can come wire up this function to your button   
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
    $("#btnAddFake").click(createListItem( _spPageContextInfo.pageListId));
},"sp.js");
```

Using a construct like this, I don't need to worry about `apply` or `Function.createDelegate` or any of that nonsense -- and I don't create a bunch of globals because everything is inside the single function. For something like this I would use in production, I would just stick a function like this inside of a module (using whatever framework you want if necessary)

Other SharePoint stuff:

Don't use your own `ctx` variable, it is one that SharePoint defines within its own JavaScript execution environment and contains a bunch of useful properties. It may be annoying, but call it something else.

You can't check if a list exists with this:

```
...
list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
if (!list) {
    alert("List not found");
    return;
} 
...
```

The call to `ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById()` will always return an `SP.List` object, even if a list with the given ID doesn't exist -- your later call to `executeQueryAsync` will let you know this, but then you'll wind up in an error callback anyway... SharePoint `ClientObject`s are always instantiated when you call the correct function, what they get "filled up" with later is entirely dependent on how they were created.

Comment: This doesn't work.  If I don't call ExecSPObjModel, I don't have an SP.ClientContext object to get .get_current() from.  What do I need to do to get a valid clientContext without ExecSPObjModel?

Comment: @SvdSinner try wrapping the jQuery event binding in `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` -- it should just be an issue with waiting for sp.js to load; I've updated my answer. And I realized you don't need `new` with `SP.ClientContext.get_current`

Comment: I am editing my question to include the version of your code that worked for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a try to this

```
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
```

replace this block with

```
ctx.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This partly works.   Switching to this syntax prevents the error, and causes the Success handler to run.  However, this.newItem.get_id() comes back as 0, and no item actually gets created.